# how to implement ExpressionWrapper, F and Sum properly in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models Product and Damaged. Product has quantity of an item and Damaged has the number of damaged quantity of that item. In my template list_product I have listed total quantity of each product. When I add number of damaged_quantity into the Damaged model it should be deducted from the number of total quantity in Product. I have implemented the following code. Everything works fine. The only problem I am having is if the total number of quantity in Product is equal to number of damaged_quantity from Damaged it doesn't show `0` in the template of product_list. How to solve it?

> models.py

```
class Damaged(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    damaged_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

> views.py

```
def list_product(request):


    products = Product.objects.annotate(
    damaged_product_quantity=Sum('damagedproducts__damaged_quantity'))

    updated_product = products.annotate(
    real_quantity = When(
        Case(quantity__gt=F('damaged_product_quantity'), then=F('quantity')-F('damaged_product_quantity')),
        Case(quantity__lte=F('damaged_product_quantity'), then=Value(0)),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
)

    damaged_products = Damaged.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'pos/list_product.html', {'products': products, 'damaged': damaged_products})
```

> list_product template

```
{% if not product.real_quantity %}
    {{product.quantity}}

{% else %}
  {{ product.real_quantity }}
{% endif %}
```

> stacktrace

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/pos/list/product/

Django Version: 2.2
Python Version: 3.6.8
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'pos',
 'bootstrap4']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/anaconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/anaconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/anaconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/web99/Desktop/onlinezeal/PosProject/pos/views.py" in list_product
  369.         output_field=IntegerField(),

File "/anaconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py" in __init__
  863.             raise TypeError("__init__() takes either a Q object or lookups as keyword arguments")

Exception Type: TypeError at /pos/list/product/
Exception Value: __init__() takes either a Q object or lookups as keyword arguments
```

Comment: can you try without the ExpressionWrapper please?

Comment: how to do it without ExpressionWrapper ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
products = Product.objects.annotate(damaged_product_quantity=Sum(
'damagedproducts__damaged_quantity')).annotate(
real_quantity=F('quantity')-F('damaged_product_quantity'))
```

Here, you don't need an ExpressionWrapper, beacuse Both `quantity` and `damaged_product_quantity` are integer values.

#### Using Conditional Expression:

```
from django.db.models import Value, When, Case

products = Product.objects.annotate(
    damaged_product_quantity=Sum('damagedproducts__damaged_quantity'))

updated_product = products.annotate(
    real_quantity = Case(
        When(quantity__gt=F('damaged_product_quantity'), then=F('quantity')-F('damaged_product_quantity')),
        When(quantity__lte=F('damaged_product_quantity'), then=Value(0))
    )
)
```

Documentation can be found [**`here`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/).

Comment: @SugAt please check the conditional expression in my answer

Comment: `__init__() takes either a Q object or lookups as keyword arguments` this error occured

Comment: which db are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql

Comment: I have tested the both versions of the code with django 2.2 and MySQL 8.0.11, and they worked. I am not sure whats happening here. Can you share the full stacktrace?

Comment: i changed my views.py with your updated conditional expression, passed `updated_product` in context and removed the `elif` part from the template.

Comment: Can you please share the full error in question please? With stactrace

Comment: @SugAt can you please try the updated conditional expression answer?

Comment: For the conditional, should it have Case on the outside and When on the inside?

Comment: I agree. Care to edit the answer please? thanks

Comment: I tried to, it says the suggested edit queue is full

Comment: No worries. Thanks, updated the answer.